# Is the 0/1 knapsack algorithm a suitable candidate here?

Tags: java, algorithm, random, knapsack-problem

I have three categories of input , each with a impact range.

1. Cat 1 : 20 - 16
2. Cat 2 : 15 - 5
3. Cat 3 : 4 -1

I have a file with say N randomly generated categories.
I am trying to take a sum of impact for all the 100 entries through a logic that looks something like this :

```
// calculate sum of impacts
getSum(){
    Generate a random class with seed as current system execution time
    for(as many entries in file){
        switch(category)
            case 1 : i = random input between 20 - 16
            case 2 : i = random input between 15 - 5
            case 3 : i = random input between 4 - 1
            some default case here
        sum = sum + i
    }
    return sum
}

.
.

// loop until you get a desired sum
while(true){
    if(Call to getSum() returns value within a desired range){
        display some statistics;
        break;
    }   
}
```

However , i see that the program generally runs infinitely , as the random generation and subsequent summation is giving result beyond the desired range. So , to get things in range ,  I have to manually tune the max-min ranges for each execution.

Can someone suggest an algorithm that will automatically vary the max min ranges for each category , by *learning* the trend of obtained sum as the program is running , so as to quickly give a solution ?

**Edit** : i have just read about the 0/1 knapsack algorithm.. and it seems promising , but unsure if that is the algorithm for this case. Any help would be great.

Comment: What language are you working in? C++?

Comment: Maybe comment out the psedocode so that someone can paste more quickly.

Comment: @DutchOven : I'm working with Java , but even if your in c++ , shouldn't cause much trouble.

Answer (score 0):

A couple band-aids:
1) use a long int instead of a regular int t give you a longer range.
2) use an unsigned long, since all of your relevant numbers are positive (then be careful of underflow errors when you subtract.

A couple possible strategies:
1) (This contradicts your question, but it is how things are usually done.) Determine the static maximum for each category, and design to it, using long unsigned int if that is large enough, or some larger data structure as necessary.
2) (This is exactly what you are asking.) Use, and build if necessary, a data structure which expands when an overflow occurs.

Solution for strategy 2:
I will get back to you on this. :)